# Why are chicken thighs sold as bone-in skin-on or boneless skinless but never boneless skin-on?

Tags: chicken, meat, poultry, butchering

Chicken thighs are fantastic pan fried skin down for that crispy texture. The bones tend to get in the way of eating them however, and they are a hassle to remove (though quick with good knife/shear technique). I'd love to be able to buy boneless skin-on thighs as they seem like the ultimate easy/juicy/flavourful cut of chicken.

Is there just such a small demand for boneless skin-on thighs that they don't bother producing them, or is there a butchery processing reason (e.g. does industrial-scale deboning damage the skin)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually while they are not easily found everywhere, some stores do sell the boneless skin-on chicken thighs and breasts. In fact, I just bought some of the thighs this past week. (I'm in the US, mid-atlantic region.)

The reason most stores don't sell them that way is because it's a less popular option and therefore in less demand than bone-in,skin-on or boneless/skinless. That said, if you shop in stores that have butchers on premise, you can ask them to bone the thighs and leave the skin on.

Back many years ago before boneless/skinless pieces became popular, it was quite easy to find the boneless thighs and breasts with the skin on.

Comment: I'd never thought of asking a butcher to bone them for me. Thank you for that detail!

Comment: I'm in London - most supermarkets sell them here as a regular product line.

Comment: Also London and I've not seen them very commonly. I just buy them with the bones in and de-bone myself. Tends to be cheaper too!